# Patterns for save data between tests in a sequence of test

Tags: python, testing, integration-testing, pytest, python-unittest

Which patterns can I use for API testing when I need to get some data and use it in other requests?

Next case for example:

```
def test_item_get():
    r = get_json('/item')
    assert r.status_code == 200


def test_item_update():
    r = get_json('/item')
    assert r.status_code == 200

    item_uuid = r.json[0]['uuid']
    assert is_uuid(item_uuid)

    r = put_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid), {'description': 'New desc'})
    assert r.status_code == 200


def test_item_manager():
    r = get_json('/item')
    assert r.status_code == 200

    item_uuid = r.json[0]['uuid']
    assert is_uuid(item_uuid)

    r = put_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid), {'description': 'New desc'})
    assert r.status_code == 200

    r = get_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid))
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert r.json['description'] = 'New desc'

    r = delete_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid))
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert r.json['result'] == True

    r = delete_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid))
    assert r.status_code == 404
```

It looks like I should to divide the `test_item_manager` into smaller parts, but I'm not sure which way to choose.

Perfectly, if there are ways with `pytest` or `unittest`, but other testing modules or even a link to the source code with the solution of similar tasks will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you will have to divide your `test_item_manager` in to multiple tests to test each CRUD operation separately . You can have one function level fixture, which would get you the `item_uuid` on which you can perform your operations.  Ofcourse , you will have to make sure your `item_uuid` fixture returns a valid `uuid` for each test.

For e.x

```
@pytest.fixture
def item_uuid():
    r = get_json('/item')
    assert r.status_code == 200
    return r.json[0]['uuid']

def test_item_get():
    # You can keep this test or remove as it gets covered under fixture.
    r = get_json('/item')
    assert r.status_code == 200


def test_item_update(item_uuid):
    assert is_uuid(item_uuid)

    r = put_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid), {'description': 'New desc'})
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert r.json['description'] = 'New desc'


def test_item_delete(item_uuid):
   r = delete_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid))
   assert r.status_code == 200
   assert r.json['result'] == True

   r = delete_json('/item/{}'.format(item_uuid))
   assert r.status_code == 404
```